# AVMutableComposition memory leak

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory-leaks

My app combines video sequences and depending on the situation it adds music to the final sequence. After add music, the app checks if user select a video for intro, then combines it to final video.

When running the profiler, I found memory leaks when I do this for the second and third times:

```
AVMutableComposition *composition = [AVMutableComposition composition];
```

[image]

When combining the initial video sequences, it does not show memory leaks. But if the app adds music and intro, it leaks memory.

When adding music I create a new composition and a new one when adding intro. It does not happen in the same part of the code.

Is it the problem? I cannot create more than one AVMutableComposition? How can I get rid of these memory leaks?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't find a perfect solution for that, but reduced the leak to only one during the course of the app by doing a singleton.

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) AVMutableComposition *composition;

static FBVideoEditor *instance = nil;

+ (FBVideoEditor*) shared {
    if (instance == nil) {
        instance = [[FBVideoEditor alloc] init];
    }
    return instance;
}

- (AVMutableComposition*) getComposition {
    if (_composition == nil) {
        _composition = [AVMutableComposition composition];
    }
    for (AVMutableCompositionTrack *track in [_composition tracks]) {
        [_composition removeTrack:track];
    }
    return _composition;
}
```

By doing this, AVMutableComposition will leak only the first time. Then, my app reuses it many times without more memory leaks.

Comment: I'm basically doing the same thing, but the memory leak is causing issues elsewhere in my debugging flow (can't release with memory leaks) - my investigations so far lead me to conclude that this is a leak in the AVFoundation framework, and we'll have to wait for Apple to address it - btw, this is on iOS 11.2.5, not sure if todays release fixes it ..

Answer (score 0):

I have also run into this issue, but I'm only doing a single assignment to my composition variable, like so:

```
    AVMutableComposition* tSilencingComposition = [AVMutableComposition composition];
```

I do not re-use the composition pointer again, rather assigning it to nil and letting ARC do its thing during the course of the app - but every time I hit this line, I get a leak reported.  It seems to be something in AVMutableComposition.

Instruments reports that I am leaking 6 bytes in this assignment, and further drilling-down produces the same reports around those FigXPC* calls ..

Comment: Thanks for you answer. I also didn't find a solution for that. But by doing a singleton I reduced the leaks to only one. See my own answer.